# Signed vs unsigned integer arithmetic operations in PIC MCU

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, embedded

I have defined the following function in mikroC PRO, to load the PR2 register of a PIC16F887 with a desired PWM frequency and duty cycle:

```
void PWM1_Duty(int PWM_freq, int duty_cycle) {

//_XTAL_FREQ DEFINED AS FOLLOWS:  #define _XTAL_FREQ   2000000
//TMR2prescal DEFINE AS FOLLOWS:  #define TMR2prescal  16

 int duty;
 int period;

//Let's first store the result in an integer variable
period=((_XTAL_FREQ/(PWM_freq*4*TMR2prescal))-1);

 //Load PR2 with the appropriate number to get the desired PWM frequency
 PR2 = ((_XTAL_FREQ/(PWM_freq*4*TMR2prescal))-1);
 //Convert the percentage duty cycle to number to load to CCPR1L reg
 duty = (((float)duty_cycle/100)*_XTAL_FREQ)/(PWM_freq*TMR2prescal);           
 
 DC1B0_bit = duty & 1;
 DC1B1_bit = (duty & 2)>>1;
 CCPR1L = duty>>2;
}
```

Then I passed the following values to the function:

- `PWM_freq = 1000`
- `duty_cycle = 50`

If I declare PWM_freq as an integer, PR2 is loaded with 233 (which is not the desired value).
But if I declare PWM_freq as an unsigned integer, the PR2 register is loaded with 30 (which is the expected value).

Another fact, is that when I store the result in an integer variable (period in the program)than assign its value to PR2, I got 30 (The desired value)

I want to understand from where this fact comes?

Comment: What value is TMR2prescal ?

Comment: Most likely, TMR2Prescal is larger then 8 (?), Causing an overflow in the result of "PWM_freq*4*TMR2prescal", which would presumably be of type "int" (depends on the type of TMR2prescal aswell, which was not given). Int is only 2 bytes wide on mikroC for PIC.

Comment: TMR2prescale is 16

Comment: Some [related reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes) over on SO which discusses the size of `int`. In embedded code it's usually 'safer' to use the `stdint.h` types like `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, etc which have explicit sizes so that you're less likely to overflow your variables (if you're paying attention that is ...).

Comment: The following are bad practices: using 8 bit microcontrollers for new designs, using floating point when coding 8 bit microcontrollers, using `int` instead of `stdint.h` when coding for microcontrollers, using signed numbers just for the heck of it (how can your PWM have a negative duty cycle). The multiple problems in this code all originate from these very bad practices.

Answer (score 8):

Mikro C ints are 16 bits. Probably you are generating an intermediate number that is too large for a signed int (+32767/-32768) but not too large for an unsigned int (65535/0). For example, TMR2prescal = 64 with an 8MHz crystal.

You can declare TMR2prescal, PWM_freq as **long** (32 bit) and it should work with signed or unsigned. Or int32_t with the appropriate header file included.

---

Edit: Consider this program with two versions of PR2 calculation and the crystal frequency set to 2MHz.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    #define _XTAL_FREQ 2000000
    
    int16_t PWM_freq = 1000, PR2, PR2a; 
    int16_t TMR2prescal = 16; 
    
    PR2 = (uint8_t) ((_XTAL_FREQ/(int16_t)(PWM_freq*(int16_t)4*TMR2prescal))-1);

    printf("PR2= %d\n",  PR2); 
    
    PR2a = (uint8_t) ((_XTAL_FREQ/(int32_t)(PWM_freq*(int32_t)4*TMR2prescal))-1);
    printf("PR2a= %d\n",  PR2a); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> PR2= 233
>
> PR2a= 30

Comment: I think that the field is a "5" in order to select the 64 rate. So the value of TMR2PRESCALE (with an E, typically) is actually 5 for the formula I see being used. (see example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxu2e.png).) But longs are often used. That's in order to force the denominator to be a long and therefore to likely cast the constant XTAL frequency to become long (it's hard to be sure what the compiler does with a simple constant that isn't typed as shown in my example case.) In any case, the OP needs write C code carefully.

Comment: @jonk I'm not sure how that formula would work if the TMR2prescal contained the code 2^n that needs to be written to CCPxCON. In any case this chip only supports 1,4, or 16 for the timer 2 prescaler (0x00, 0x01, 0x02/0x03 in LS bits of T2CON), so it's not quite the same as my example, but I think the answer is fundamentally correct.

Comment: Or if it's known that it will not affect rounding, rewrite it as `_XTAL_FREQ / TMR2prescal / (PWM_freq*4)` or so. (Especially if `TMR2prescal` depends on the clock frequency, I suppose one could just consider `_XTAL_FREQ / TMR2prescal`  a constant? I'm not sure if that's how it's supposed to be, but this answer seems to imply that.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes.. it's a constant. In this case the result is 8 bits and the _XTAL_FREQ/TMR2prescal in this case will fit in a 16-bit signed or unsigned 16 bit int. However, if we change the crystal to an 8MHz one, the result will fit into a 16 bit unsigned but not signed, and with a 16MHz crystal it won't fit into either. Similar thing if you leave the crystal frequency as-is and reduce TMR2prescal to 4 or 1. If the PWM frequency is being recalculated frequently it might make sense to optimize it for speed on an 8-bit processor, ofc, but usually it's one and done. Duty cycle is another matter.

Comment: In fact if the PWM_freq is constant, a smart compiler should optimize any calculations away and just have a single 8-bit constant loaded into PR2. The calculations make it much more understandable in the source code and it's clear(er) how to modify it if things like crystal frequency change.

Answer (score 6):

From the values given we can deduce that `_XTAL_FREQ` is defined as `2 000 000`.
`TMR2prescal` is also of type `int` or a type with a lesser conversion rank.

Thus, as all operands in `PWM_freq*4*TMR2prescal` are of type `int` (literal `4` is also type `int`), the temporary R-value that holds the result will also be of type `int`.

`int` is 2 bytes wide on mikroC for PIC, meaning it can only hold the values between and including `+32767/-32768`.

For the values given, the result would be `64 000`, which overflows the result. Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C, so whatever result you get is meaningless...

A possible solution would be to use `4L` for the literal instead of `4`, which would make the literal of the type `long`. [The standard conversion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) would cause the other types to be converted to `long` for the computation.